# Copy Field from a Table to Be used In a Query For Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run a query that copies information from one table and then places that stored data into a new query.

Query 1 details:
For table qu_pap_users there is a column that is named userid.  I need to find that column and a specific data field in that column called b793bca3, and then move to the adjacent column called accountuserid and copy the value in that column that relates to the value in the userid column.

I then need to paste that value into the query below where the XXX is...

```
$sql = "update `qu_g_users` set `rstatus` = 'D' where `accountuserid` IS 'XXX';
```

Any idea how to write the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding on this, we need to find the row in table qu_pap_users with userid='b793bca3' and copy the value of accountuserid to your update statement.
If my understanding is right, we can do as follows

```
$sql = "update qu_g_users set rstatus = 'D' where accountuserid in (select accountuserid from qu_pap_users where userid='b793bca3' )" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you essentially want the same field value(s) (UserID & AccountUserID) in both tables?

You want to insert the value(s) of UserID from **qu_pap_users** into your second table, in your AccountUserID field?